# Using Entity Print to generate several PDFs of a Webform submission

Tags: webforms, 8

This may be too vague a question as I'm just starting to work through this. Would very much appreciate any pointers/experiences if people have done something similar.

Functionality I'm hoping for:
User completes a webform survey and upon completion they are able to download two PDFs that have differing data/results form specific sections of the webform.

A more concrete example, the webform first asks profile questions about age and job type, conditionally on that the second half of the form pulls in different questions (ie. if you answered being under 50, you get question set A, if over 50 get question set B). Once the user submits the form they could download two separate PDFs, one a summary of their profile, and the second a summary of their answers to the conditional question sets.

I've got webform and entity print running, and can see the 'view/print pdf' function added to webform submissions, and have been able to link to that PDF on the confirmation page. But I'm not sure about the best way to approach creating two separate PDFs. Views seems the best approach, but how would I link it all together? Is there another way? Like I said, apologies, this is probably too vague, just trying to avoid going down dead-end paths.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "Webform Entity Print (PDF) Attachment" module included with the Webform module to create different PDF versions of a submission.

This [video](https://www.videodrupal.org/video/20190129/sending-webform-email-attachments) includes a little more information about attachment elements.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like it will do the trick perfectly!